# JS Error - Unresponsive Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dynamically adding elements to my webpage using the code below. It works, but it freezes the page. Can anyone explain why this would be happening?

```
 <script>
            $(function() {
                var ruler = $("#ruler").height();
                var body = $("body").height();
                while (ruler <= body) {
                    $("#rulerStart").append("<div class='lineLarge'></div><div class='lineSmall'></div>");
                };
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: you need to add a check inside while so the loop does not run forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ruler = $("#ruler").height();
var body = $("body").height();
```

These values are static. Once set, always set.

You'll need to reset them inside the loop:

```
$(function() {
    var ruler = $("#ruler").height();
    var body = $("body").height();
    while (ruler <= body) {
        $("#rulerStart").append("<div class='lineLarge'></div><div class='lineSmall'></div>");
        ruler = $("#ruler").height();
        body = $("body").height();
    };
});
```